# Use of \r (carriage return) in python regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use regex to match every character between a string and a `\r` character :

```
text = 'Some text\rText to find !\r other text\r'
```

I want to match `'Text to find !'`. I already tried :

```
re.search(r'Some text\r(.*)\r', text).group(1)
```

But it gives me : `'Text to find !\r other text'`

It's surprising because it works perfectly when replacing `\r` by `\n` :

```
re.search(r'Some text\n(.*)\n', 'Some text\nText to find !\n other text\n').group(1)
```

returns `Text to find !`

Do you know why it behaves differently when we use `\r` and `\n` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.*` is greedy in nature so it is matching longest match available in:

```
r'Some text\r(.*)\r
```

Hence giving you:

```
re.findall(r'Some text\r(.*)\r', 'Some text\rText to find !\r other text\r')
['Text to find !\r other text']
```

However if you change to non-greedy then it gives expected result as in:

```
re.findall(r'Some text\r(.*?)\r', 'Some text\rText to find !\r other text\r')
['Text to find !']
```

---

Reason why `re.findall(r'Some text\n(.*)\n', 'Some text\nText to find !\n other text\n')` gives just `['Text to find !']` is that DOT matches any character except line break and `\n` is a line break. If you enable `DOTALL` then again it will match longest match in:

```
>>> re.findall(r'Some text\n([\s\S]*)\n', 'Some text\nText to find !\n other text\n')
['Text to find !\n other text']

>>> re.findall(r'(?s)Some text\n(.*)\n', 'Some text\nText to find !\n other text\n')
['Text to find !\n other text']
```

Which again changes behavior when you use non-greedy quantifier:

```
re.findall(r'(?s)Some text\n(.*?)\n', 'Some text\nText to find !\n other text\n')
['Text to find !']
```

Answer (score 4):

That is correct and expected behavior since `.` by default in Python `re` does not match LF chars only, it matches CR (carriage return) chars.

See the [`re` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-0):

> `.`
>            (Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character except a newline. If the [DOTALL flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) has been specified, this matches any character including a newline.

You can easily check that with the [following code](https://ideone.com/ZrQr3C):

```py
import re
unicode_lbr = '\n\v\f\r\u0085\u2028\u2029'
print( re.findall(r'.+', f'abc{unicode_lbr}def') )
# => ['abc', '\x0b\x0c\r\x85\u2028\u2029def']
```

To match between two carriage return chars you need to use the negated character class:

```py
r'Some text\r([^\r]*)\r'
r'Some text\r([^\r]*)'   # if the trailing CR char does not have to exist
```

In case you want to match between the leftmost and rightmost occurrences of `\r` chars (the outer CR chars) including any chars in between you can use a mere `.*` with `re.DOTALL`:

```py
re.search(r'(?s)Some text\r(.*)\r', text)
re.search(r'Some text\r(.*)\r', text, re.DOTALL)
```

where `(?s)` is an inline modifier equal to `re.DOTALL` / `re.S`.